# How c++ works with overflow in this specific question?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I executed this c++ code using visual studio 2019, and I got the degree sign as the answer.

```
int main()
{
    char ch1 = 760;
    cout <<ch1;
    return 0;
}
```

I have this as the result `°`, but I expected an integer as the output. I know the binary representation, so I expected to see -8. but I see the degree sign.

Comment: I expected an integer as the output. I know the binary representation, so I expected to see -8. but I see the degree sign.

Comment: UB if char is signed; or 760 MOD 256 if char is unsigned and 8-bits See __Overflows__ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @RichardCritten That only applies to assignment, not initialization.  It is either well defined or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: You are seeing a degree sign because you are sending a `char` to `std::cout`. It assumes you want to display textual output and so it shows the character with that numeric value. You might cast the variable to something like `int` to display the numeric value but that doesn't answer your question about overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what the underlying type of `char` is.  The initialization rule we have to consider is [[dcl.init]/17.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.8) which states:

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. Standard conversions will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed. When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

So, from that we see it will preform a standard conversion.  Going to that section we get to the integer conversion section ([[conv.integral]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral)) and we have

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

and

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

So, if `char` is unsigned then you'll get `760 mod 2^CHAR_BITS` as the value for `ch1`.  If it is signed, then you'll need to see how your implementation handles overflow.  In no case though is this undefined behavior, just straight up well defined behavior or implementation defined behavior.

---

The reason you see a symbol after all of this is because `ch1` is a `char`.  `std::cout::operator<<` is type aware and has a special overload for `char`'s that print out the character from the character set that has the integer value that `ch1` holds.

If you want to see an integer you need to cast it like

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(ch1);
```

Comment: @MooingDuck I missed that part.  I've added to the answer.

Comment: why degree sign? is that unicode representation of degree sign?

Comment: @Alireza That just happens to be the character that matches the bit pattern `ch1` holds.

Comment: @Alireza:  That just happens to be the character that matches the bit pattern ch1 holds, according to whatever program you're using to view the output, usually the terminal program. By changing the settings in that program, the output may render differently.

Answer (score 2):

With the proper warning enabled I get for your code the following (**with clang**):

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 760 to -8
```

Now, it is just a warning, not a compilation error. So the code runs. From this point it goes to printing the character which is represented by this value. Which is related to how std::ostream print chars.

If you want to see -8 as the output you can do:

```
std::cout << (int)ch1;
```

However this depends on the representation of char which is platform dependent and can be signed or unsigned, if it is unsigned you will probably see the output as 248.

Comment: Signed or unsigned can depend on compiler settings as well, most have an option to choose explicitly...